# How would I compare a number to a range of numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to compare a range of numbers against a single number, basically like this in simple terms:

```
if X through Y equals Z, then do {}
```

What would be the proper way to do something like that in Javascript?

**CLARIFICATION**

I want to check if any number between `X and Y` is equal to `Z`

Comment: A range implies a loop. Show us the loop.

Comment: So you're checking that `X through Y` are the same number as `Z`? So `X` and `Y` are indices of an array, or something?

Comment: I don't have a loop.
This is being used for collision detection of 2 boxes.

Comment: You want to compare every number in the range against z?

Comment: what does equals mean? x <= z <= y?

Comment: I'm checking if `Z` is equal to any number between `X and Y`,  
Triztian is correct.

Comment: Any, I say it in my clarification.

Comment: @ryansworld10: But your pseudocode implies "all".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A range doesn't equal a number, do you mean that the number falls within the range?

```
if (1 <= Z && Z <= 25 ) {
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to determine if `Z` is *in* the range `[X, Y]`, then you can do:

```
if (X < Z && Z < Y) {
    // do stuff.
}
```

Otherwise, a range can't equal a number.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [...];

var compareRange = function(arr, x, y, z){

  for(var i=x; i<=y; i++){
    if(arr[i] != z){
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if elements 1 through 3 are all 1:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
var allOne = arr.slice(1, 4).filter(
    function(val) { return val !== 1; }).length === 0;
```

---

**EDIT**

Even better, thanks to `@am not i am`

```
var arr = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
var allOne = arr.slice(1, 4).every(function (val) { return val === 1; });
```

Comment: +1 because this was what the question was asking, irrespective of what OP wanted. Though you could also use `.every()` in place of `.filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

First the range function:

```
function range(a,b){
    var r = [a];
    for(var i=a;i<=b;i++){
         r.push(i);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Now use the function and make the comparison:

```
var a = range(1,6); // Range
var z = 7;
if(a.indexOf(z) > -1){
    // Collision !!!
}else{
   // No collision, I suppose...
}
```

Comment: For readability you could make a "within" function

 if within(1,8,value)
   dostuff()

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have completely understood your question.
I made a function that compares a number `n` to a range of numbers between `min` and `max`. This function returns an integer `r` from 1 to 5

- `n` is less than `min`, `r` =  1
- `n` is equal to `min`, `r` = 2
- `n` is between `min` and `max`,  `r` = 3
- `n` is equal to `max`,  `r` = 4
- `n` is greater than `max`, `r` = 5

```
function compareToRange(n,min,max){
var r=((n<min)*1+(n==min)*2+((n>min)&&(n<max))*3+(n==max)*4+(n>max)*5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Tsundoku!